# Где грань достаточно веской причины для отклонения кода при Code Review?

Tags: php, team, инспекция-кода

Вопрос по поводу проведения Code review со стороны тим-лида.
Где грань, что нужно отправлять на исправление, а на что можно просто забивать? Насколько высока должна быть планка качества?

Пример: был написан код (коменты мои):

```
$averageSumPerMonth = Orders::getInstance()->calculateAveragePricePerMonth(Auth::getAccountId()); // 15 or null
if ($averageSumPerMonth) {
   $averageSumPerMonth = $accountService->getBalanceService()->getAmountString($averageSumPerMonth, 0); // '15 рублей'
}
```

Строка результата `$averageSumPerMonth` далее передаётся в шаблон.
Так как кроме этого кода в методе (контроллере) ещё много подобного кода, мне кажется логичным вынести это в отдельный метод, чтобы также избавится от переписывания одной переменной значениями разных типов.
Достаточное ли это обоснование чтобы завернуть код или лишние придирки?

Я согласен, что никто не умрёт, если этот код попадёт в продакшен. Но хочется держать планку качества выше.

Основой вопрос - как понять не перегибаешь ли ты палку?
Насколько высока планка качества которую нужно соблюсти, чтобы пройти code review в вашей компании?

Comment: Если `$averageSumPerMonth` используется не единожды и есть предположение, что то может измениться, то однозначно вынести, но только как то страшновато оно у вас выглядит ;). Если честно, но до конца понял `также избавится от переписывания одной переменной значениями разных типов`, что вы тут имели ввиду? И возможно станет понятно из-за чего тим-лид завернул код...возможно не только  мне...

Comment: Не принципиально, главное разобраться)). Еще раз взглянул на отрывок, по сути все пляски с `$averageSumPerMonth` можно сделать внутри и отдавать либо `null`, либо `15 рублей`, имхо.

Comment: @borodatych об этом и речь. Вынести в метод который возвращает null либо 15 рублей. `также избавится от переписывания одной переменной значениями разных типов` - первый метод возвращает число а второй конвертит это число в валюту пользователя и возвращает строку вида 15$ или 300 рублей

Comment: Вам правильно ответил @Ипатьев. Это все сугубо индивидуально, мнения могут и будут расходиться, однозначного ответа не будет. Я считаю, что стоит вынести, кто то со мной не согласиться. Не в обиду, но  с такими вопросами явно не сюда.

Comment: @Alexey Каждый программист исходит из собственных представлений о качестве кода.  Поэтому "планка" - это ваше внутренняя культура программирование, ваше личное понимание, а также ваша общечеловеческая культура.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29979/discussion-on-question-by-alexey-------).

Answer (score 4):

Если бы ответ на данный вопрос можно было формализовать, то профессия тим-лида стала бы ненужной. Здесь только опыт и контекст. Контекст может включать множество факторов.

Боюсь, вопрос в целом не слишком подходит под формат SO. Здесь любят конкретные ответы на конкретные вопросы, а по данной теме ни того ни другого в принципе не может быть.